# Not able to list files under folder for dashboard through metadata api

Tags: metadata-api, dashboard, xml, list-metadata

I am trying to list all the files which are present inside a folder for the dashboard metadata type.

> for example:- I want to see what are the files which are inside the Service_Dashboards folder of Dashboards folder using listmetadata() call.

[image]

This is what I tried...

1. First I did a normal list call to find what are all files and folders present inside the dashboards directory.
   [image].

This gave the correct result regarding the files and folder present in the dashboard folder.

2. Now, the second task is to traverse in a folder called Service_Dashboards and list all the files present into that.
   here is the list call what I tried
   [image]
   Irrespective of giving details about the files present inside the folder, it is giving the result the same as in step 1.

Any lead, where I am doing wrong?

Comment: might help (https://www.pocketsoap.com/weblog/2008/10/1826.html)

Comment: This is code helping platform so if you can post code (not screenshots), it helps to copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type to `Dashboard` instead of `DashboardFolder`.

Basically for all foldered metadata (Dashboards, Reports, EmailTemplates and Documents), you first need to list folders (which you did in step1) and then list individual components within a folder.

Ref: [listMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadataquery.htm)

Comment: Thanks @metasync...
This is working